# bash script only starts new jobs when old batch is finished

Tags: bash, multicore, timing

I am trying to run 24 versions of the same code on an 8 core machine.  The code takes many many hours to run and I only want to run 8 at a time so I was wondering if it was possible to write a bash script which would run 8 and then when those were complete immediately start the next 8 and so on?
I basically dont want all 24 to start and then run incredibly slowly!
Thanks,
Jack

EDIT 1: (More details on the run)
The code runs with the following command:
nohup ./MyCode MyInputFile 2> Myoutput

Comment: Mind posting the code or at least how you run it? If it's not a normal command, the solution may vary.

Comment: Sure thing @konsolebox please see above

Comment: Does MyCode, MyInputFile and/or Myoutput vary on every instance? Which one is changing?

Comment: MyCode stays the same on each run but I am varying the input and I want the output pipes out to a different file each time so I can keep track of each

Comment: Well as `user000001` suggested you could use `parallel` for that but where do you get those varying input, and how do you decide the filename? From what source?

Comment: in a folder accessible from the source code I have files such as:
Myinput1, Myinput2 etc. and then up until now I have been just listing 8 versions of the above command for each input, but now I need 24, with only 8 running at any one time

Comment: And your output varies as well based from the file to process? e.g. `Myinput1.out`

Comment: Exactly, the only bit I dont unsertand is forcing it to wait for the previous 8 lines to be done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use gnu parallel

```
seq 1 24 | parallel -P 8 ./myscript
```

Or with xargs:

```
seq 1 24 | xargs -l -P 8 ./myscript
```

Update:

If you want to run the script with Myinput1 Myinput2 Myinput3 .. as parameters you can do

```
find . -name 'Myinput*' -print0 | parallel -0 -P 8 ./myscript {1}
```

or with your command:

```
find . -name 'Myinput*' -print0 | parallel -0 -P 8 nohup ./myscript {1}  2> Myoutput
```

Comment: Thanks @user00001, so if I had three copies of that last line running from 0 -> 24 in total it would run in parallel but not overlap?

Comment: You can make that something like `... | parallel -0 -P 8 nohup ./myscript {1} '2>' {1}.out`. I'm not sure if `nohup` is necessary this time though.

Comment: @JackMedley Yes it would run once for each file, with 8 processes running at a time

Comment: Sorry but just to clarify what is the '...' in your above comment, so far I think I only understand how to get the first 8 going, but not how to do they next 8 once the initial batch have completed

Comment: You probably mean @konsolebox's comment.

Comment: @JackMedley  It's `find . -name 'Myinput*' -print0`.

Comment: @JackMedley Gnu parallel will start the next processes once the first 8 start finishing. That's the whole point of the command.

Comment: Also, the `find` command would search recursively. To match only those files in the current directory, do `printf "%s\n" Myinput* | parallel -P 8 nohup ./myscript {1} '2>' {1}.out`

Comment: Ok great! So that one line does exactly what I need :) thats fantastic thanks guys

Comment: @konsolebox As long as there are no newlines in the filename :) In that case you should use `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: @user000001 Yeah I wanted to note that as well earlier but the `find` command is better until I realized that you still need to add `-maxdepth 1`. Overall using `printf` would be simpler since you didn't have to use an external binary and having `\n` in filenames in this session is unlikely. And also matching directories.

Comment: Na its a 'normal' filename, I didnt even know newlines were allowed in filenames!

Comment: Hmm it turns out 'parallel' isnt even installed on the server *sigh*

Comment: @JackMedley You can use xargs then (which is almost certainly installed): `find . -name 'Myinput*' -print0 | xargs -0l -P 8 -I {} nohup  ./myscript {}`

Comment: once again I've never come across xargs (but it is installed at least!) so may I just double check that the '{}' at the end there contains the generalised input file name?

Comment: @JackMedley Correct. It is defined by the `-I` option

Comment: @JackMedley Re: installing GNU Parallel. See http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Answer (score 2):

yet another way :

```
for f1 in {1..3};do 
   for f2 in {1..8};do
     echo "$f1,$f2;"
     nohup ./MyCode MyInputFile 2> Myoutput &
   done
   wait
done
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to wait of all 8 processes to finish before starting the next 8, which could potentially lead to high delays if the execution times vary significantly for different input files

Comment: Since I dont have parallel installed (and cant install it) I'll use this.  is this generalised to multiple inputs through something like:

nohup ./MyCode MyInput${8*(f1-1) + f2} 2> MyOutput${8*(f1-1) + f2} &

Comment: you can also change the wait to : ps -Ajf | grep -c yourprocess and manage the process based on how many processes are running